# Mi app se cierra al utilizar TextMatcher

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

Buen día.

Tengo un pequeño problema. Tengo un método que muestra un cuadro de dialogo en la zona inferior y este permitirá rellenar la información de una rutina de ejercicio. Sin embargo quiero implementar, que al momento de escribir en un EditTex (llamado txtNameRoutine) se modifique en tiempo real un TexView que es el titulo, pero se cambiara conforme el ususario coloque el nombre de la rutina. Sin embargo, al momento de invocar el metodo que realiza la escucha de los cambios, mi aplicacion se cierra. Y solo me manda un error de NullPointerExcepcion. Y entiendo que el EditText esta vacio y espera un valor, sin embargo aunque le establezca un valor al EditText antes de realizar la escucha, y lo valide aún se cierra. ¿Que puedo hacer?

```
   private void showBottonDialog(){
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.botton_info_add);

    dialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
            // Cambiar el texto de labelAddRoutine después de que el diálogo se muestre completamente
            changeLabelRoutine();
        }
    });

    dialog.show();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    if (window != null) {
        window.setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        window.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        window.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        window.getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    }

}

private void changeLabelRoutine(){
    final String DEFAULT_TEXT = "Agregar Rutina";

    txtNameRoutine.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // Actualizar el TextView mientras se está cambiando el texto en el EditText
            labelAddRoutine.setText(s.length() > 0 ? s : DEFAULT_TEXT);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }

    });
}
```

Adicional, si no llamo al metodo, si funciona ShowBottonDialog. El cual por si sirve de informacion adicional, viene llamado de un boton llamado btnAdd. El cual agrega CardViews, dependiendo de la info llenada en el ShowButtonDialog. Los xml y ID´s Estan correctamente llamados y agregados, desde un metodo initComponents.

Muchisimas gracias. Un saludo

Comment: Es importante revisar el logcat, que error se muestra? agregalo a tu pregunta por favor

Comment: Hola, es importante saber que esta pregunta debería incluir más detalles para aclarar el problema.